# Celsius temperature table error

Tags: java

So, i'm supposed to display a table that gives the Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion from 94F to 104F by 0.5 increments using a for loop and a celsius method that accepts a Fahrenheit temperature as an argument.
(we are just learning about methods this week)
why am I getting this error? and is this code headed in the right direction?

```
FahrenheitToCelsius.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
                fhdeg, celdeg(fhdeg) );
                       ^
  symbol:   method celdeg(double)
  location: class FahrenheitToCelsius
  1 error
```

FahrenheitToSelsius.java

```
/* PC 5.6 - Fahrenheit to Celsius 
   -------------------------
   Programmer: xxxxxxxxxxx
   Date: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   -------------------------
   This program will convert Fahrenheit to Celsius and display the
   results.
*/
// ---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7
// 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

public class FahrenheitToCelsius
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("Temperature Conversion Table");
      System.out.println("____________________________");
      System.out.println("  Fahrenheit      Celsius  ");
   }
   public static double celsius(double fhdeg)
   {

      for (fhdeg = 0; fhdeg >=94; fhdeg+=0.5)
      {
      double celdeg = 0;
      celdeg = 5.0/9 * fhdeg-32;
      System.out.printf( "    %5.1d           %4.1d\n", 
                    fhdeg, celdeg(fhdeg) );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This question has **nothing** to do with Javascript and so I have removed the tag so it does not frustrate the Javascript experts by drawing them to a completely off-topic question.

Comment: What do you mean by this: `celdeg(fhdeg)`? It makes no sense and the compiler is correct to complain.

Comment: so, yes, where have you defined `celdeg`?

Comment: apologies gentlemen, I was unaware that it was calling the method, I thought it was using my variable (celdeg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `celdeg(fhdeg)` means that you are calling a method called `celdeg` passing an argument called `fhdeg`. You get the error because there is no method called `celdeg()`.

By the statement of the problem, though, I guess you don't need to create such method. Instead, you just need to iterate over a range of degrees in Fahrenheit and display the equivalent value in Celsius. Your `for` loop could be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Temperature Conversion Table");
    System.out.println("____________________________");
    System.out.println("  Fahrenheit      Celsius  ");

    // From 94F to 104F, with increments of 0.5F
    for (double fhdeg = 94.0; fhdeg < 104.5; fhdeg += 0.5) {
        // Calculate degree in Celsius by calling the celsiusFromFahrenheit method
        double celdeg = celsiusFromFahrenheit(fhdeg);
        // Display degrees in Fahrenheit and in Celsius
        System.out.printf( "    %.2f           %.2f\n", fhdeg, celdeg);
    }
}

static double celsiusFromFahrenheit(double fhdeg) {
    return (5. / 9.) * fhdeg - 32;
}
```

Comment: okay, @Anderson Vieira that makes a bit of sense, I didn't know it was calling the method...I guess I should have used celsius(fhdeg) instead? I was assuming my variable was being used...

Comment: That is right. You need to create a separate method that will just convert a value from Fahrenheit to Celsius. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: wrote that before refreshing my page. thanks so much for your help. might b bugging you again soon. lol. couple of questions, how come our printf formulas are so different (I had a family emergency and missed that section of the chapter)

Comment: In this page (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) there is a table that explains the meaning of the symbols used in printf. Basically, %d is used for integers (int, long) and %f is used for floating point numbers (float, double). %.2f prints a float using two decimal digits after the dot.